# ildasm and .ldarg - what happend inside?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, cil, il

using c#, ,Net framework 4.5 notePad

Try understand principles of CIL (IL) language. Currently create 2 simple method

```
 public static Int32 Add(Int32 a, Int32 b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    public Int32 Add1(Int32 a, Int32 b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
```

After opening in ildasm.exe got

[image: ildasm result]

**Question**

Why in Add method CIL make loading argument in stack 0 and in second in stack 1 - Where used stack 0 in method Add1
Or i something missed?

Comment: Not sure why are you calling them “stack 0” and “stack 1”. You're loading e.g. argument 0 *into* the IL stack, you're not loading from the IL stack.

Comment: I'm just start to read about CIL and found that in this case CIl used something like stack for storing arguments. Q-tu of arguments defined by `.maxstack 2`, so I think that this command load argument in some stack - really not shure - If I wrong - please correct me

Comment: Yeah, CIL is stack based: `ldarg.1` means “load argument 1 and push it onto the stack”. But it doesn't make sense to say “stack 0” the way you did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first method gets passed two arguments, `a` (0) and `b` (1). Your second gets passed three arguments, `this` (0), `a` (1), and `b` (2). Even though you're not using `this`, it's still there.

Comment: another question - if I use `.maxstack 2` countig start from 0 - like 0,1,2 ?

Comment: This was actually surprising for me, in C++-based languages `this` is passed through a register, usually `ecx`, bypassing the stack altogether.

Comment: @Blindy This question is about IL, not about the x86 assembly. When the IL is compiled into machine code, `this` will be passed though a register.

Comment: @Kirill "another question - if I use .maxstack" - I'm not completely sure, but if I recall correctly, the stack is considered a different area of memory from where the parameters and local variables are stored.

Comment: maxstack is related to the growth of execution stack. Calling a method with 4 parameters on an instance variable, requires a stack of 5
(`ldarg.0,ldloc.0,ldloc.1,ldloc.2,ldloc.3,callvirt MyClass.Method`)
Don't think to hard about it, usually ilgenerator is too conservative, you may want to hack it via reflection and up it to 8.

Comment: @MichaelB You mean 5, right, instead of 6? There are six instructions, but only five of those put something on the stack.

Comment: Yeah sorry, typed too quickly.